# Silverlight BusyIndicator Background Colour

Tags: silverlight, toolkit, busyindicator

Is there a simple way of changing the background colour of the default busy indicator from the default grey to white gradient to another colour?

Example image of the default busy indicator can be found
[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/delay/BusyIndicator-Default.png)

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Well, its simple.

to use the toolkit you must declare it namespace in your xaml class(i think you've done that ok ?)

Like this :

```
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
```

After this you must declare your toolkit :

```
<toolkit:BusyIndicator BackGround="White" >
  <elements that need a busy indicator>
</toolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

You can do what you want just by changing the property BackGround.

Hope it Helps

Comment: I had already tried this but this appears to only set the background overlay colour to white rather than the dialog box for the busy indicator. In the end I just created my own custom busy indicator.