# Transparent busy indicator

Tags: c#, wpf, busyindicator

I'm using busy indicator from wpftoolkit library. This is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="BusyControl.MainWindow"           
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:BusyIndicator Name="ProgressIndicator" IsBusy="False" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Resources/loading.gif" Width="150" Height="50" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ProgressIndicator, Path=BusyContent}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
            <xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Style>
            </xctk:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
            <Grid>
                <Button Content="Click me" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Width="100" Height="50"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </xctk:BusyIndicator>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But my busy indicator looks like

[image: before]

but I need transparent busy indicator like this

[image: After]

How can I do that?

Comment: The problem with the first one is that some of the greyness is masked by the colour of the background. Nothing in the first picture suggests its not transparaent.

Comment: In sources of wpftoolkit library I saw that parent elenemt of ContentPresenter is a border that has gray background. Is there any way to change background of this border except source changes?

Comment: Ok, I found solution in this post [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984371/silvelight-busyindicator-background-color-for-the-message-box). I can use my own style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will be either styling or changing the template. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712787/is-it-possible-to-change-the-busy-animation-in-the-busyindicator-of-extended-wpf) is a question with an answer that shows changing the Template and Styling of that control.

Of course the devil is in the detail... you'll need to do some research to find out specifically what the structure of the control is, to work out how you want to style it. And if you haven't done this kind of thing, I should manage your expectations that it may take a little time to work out what you need to do.

Comment: The answer in the other thread is to a different question. This doesn't answer the question of how to make the BusyIndicator transparent. Merely setting the BusyContentTemplate - even with a Background color of Transparent won't make the BusyIndicator transparent.